# Sharepoint 2010, add an item to a list based on a specific content type?

Tags: 2010

Using object model I need to add an item to a list. The list has 4 custom content types. Depending on data provided I need the item to be of a specific content type.

How is this done?

Using SPListItem oItem = list.AddItem(); does not accept a content type as a parameter. 
Neither can you set it later it seems the property is read only.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also have the same problem... can you please help me if you found the solution for that...
thanks...

Comment: user4928 - if you have a simliar problem that my answer does not solve, then please create a new question and explain why my answer isn't relevant. The answer to your problem may help others! :)

Answer (score 7):

Use SPList.Items.Add() to return the item you're adding (as an instance of SPListItem), instead of SPList.AddItem().

Then you can update the ContentTypeId using myListItem["ContentTypeId"] to set the content type.

Here's an example: http://asadewa.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/adding-a-custom-content-type-specific-item-on-a-sharepoint-list/